# Infinite connected sum of S^n

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am curious about the following statement :

Statement : Infinite connected sum of $S^n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Any hint, proof of reference will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of an infinite connected sum?

Comment: The infinite connected sum should be homeomorphic to an infinite cylinder, not $\Bbb R^n$. See [this from Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/connected-sum/)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: that would be a bi-infinite connected sum. There's different ways of taking an infinite connect sum.

Comment: In fact, you could get a punctured sphere with arbitrarily many punctures $\geq 1$.

Comment: In further fact, you can get $S^n\setminus C$ where $C$ is a Cantor set. :)

Answer (score 6):

Think of a nested countable sequence of $(n-1)$-spheres in $\mathbb R^n$ starting with the unit sphere and going out to $\infty$. The annuli between each sphere are homeomorphic to $S^n$ with two disks removed. So this realizes the infinite connected sum.

Comment: Dear Cheerful Parsnip, you are saying that infinite connected sum is this: in each step $n$ we have connected sum of $n$ spheres and a cap removed from last one? Why not this one: $M_1=M, M_2=M\# M,\  M_3=M\# M\# M,\ \dots\  M_n=M\# M\#\dots\# M$ and $n\to\infty$? see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4340733/272127)

Comment: @C.F.G no I am not saying that. I am saying line up a countable sequence of spheres in a line and then tube them together. As I mentioned above, infinite connected sum is actually not well defined in general.